# How to choose when to split a string with comma

Tags: c++

I have a string that needs to be split by commas, but there is a comma in the string that I do not want to split on.

So, my string is:

```
Let's eat, Granny,Happy,22,Chicken
```

I want to split it like this:

```
Let's eat, Granny
Happy
22
Chicken
```

But I get this instead:

```
Let's eat
 Granny
Happy
22
Chicken
```

How do I split this string without messing with the first comma? I do have one idea, which is that the comma I want to ignore has whitespace after it, and I may be able to take advantage of that, right? Please correct me if I am wrong.

Here is the code I have written so far:

```
string delimiter = ",";
string test = "Let's eat, Granny,Happy,22,Chicken,";
size_t pos = 0;
string token;

while((pos = test.find(delimiter)) !=String::npos){ //position of comma

    token = test.substr(0, pos); //read in string at position of comma

}
```

Comment: That sounds reasonable. You could also try skipping the first comma.

Comment: The rule is to split when the comma is between no space char ?

Comment: Yeah I could but say I were to use a different string that didn't have a comma I needed to avoid then that'd be a bit of a problem too:/

Comment: Just don't remove the comma and accidentally eat Granny. That would be rude.

Comment: Yes exactly what I want to do. But I don't want to split when there's a white space

Comment: Do you HAVE to use a comma to separate strings?  Why not something more unique and thus more easily parsed, like `|` (pipe) or `\t` (tab) instead?

Comment: Yeah I have to use a comma to split sadly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given the data you are limited to, a comma is really not a reliable separator, unless you can *guarantee* that any ignorable commas are *always* followed by whitespace.  If so, you can do something like this:

```cpp
char delimiter = ',';
string test = "Let's eat, Granny,Happy,22,Chicken,";
size_t start = 0, end;
string token;

do
{
    end = test.find(delimiter, start);

    while ((end != string::npos) &&
           ((end+1) < test.size()) &&
           (test[end+1] == ' ')) // <-- or: isspace(test[end+1])
    {
        end = test.find(delimiter, end+2);
    }

    if (end == string::npos)
        token = test.substr(start);
    else
        token = test.substr(start, end-start);

    // use token as needed...

    if (end == string::npos)
        break;

    start = end + 1;
}
while (true);
```

[Live Demo](https://ideone.com/XUyHLZ)

Answer (score 1):

A possible solution is to use regex to tokenize your string:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iterator>
#include <regex>

int main()
{
    std::vector<std::string> items;
    std::string text = "Let's eat, Granny,Happy,22,Chicken";
    std::regex comma_re(",(?!\\s)",
            std::regex_constants::ECMAScript | std::regex_constants::icase);

    std::copy( std::sregex_token_iterator(text.begin(), text.end(), comma_re, -1),
               std::sregex_token_iterator(),
               std::back_inserter(items));

    for (const std::string& item : items){
        std::cout << item << std::endl;
    }
}
```

Now, all your separated items are in `items`

---

**Regular expression explanation**:
Match a comma `,` which is not followed by a space `(?!\\s)`